# Primary Ideals satisfy Property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Let $I$ be a primary ideal and $p$ the corresponding associated prime to $R/I$. show that $p \supset I \supset p^{n}$, for some integer $n$. I understand that $p \supset I$ because a submodule of $M \subset R/I \cong R/p \implies p \supset I$, but how do I show that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I \supset p^{n}$?

Comment: Yes I mean to say that $R$ is Noetherian. The 2 equivalent definitions I was told were $ab \in I \implies a \in I$ or $b^{n} \in I$ for some $n$, which is equivalent to $|AP(R/I)| = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $R$ is noetherian, $p$ has a finite set of generators, say $p=(g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_k)$.

For each of these $g_i$'s, there is some power $g_i^{n_i}$ that is contained in $I$. Now note that
$$
p^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k}\subseteq \left(g_1^{n_1},g_2^{n_2},\ldots,g_k^{n_k}\right)\subseteq I
$$